# Why does my Qt C++ application launch behind a "MyApplication is ready" notification in GNOME?

Tags: qt, gnome

I have just tried GNOME after a long time using KDE.

I am writing a C++ qt application. If I run it from a console with

```
$> ./my_application
```

-- instead of the application main window I get a notification at the top which says

```
My Application
"My Application" is ready
```

and when I click that I actually get my program.

The funny thing is that if I try it with another program, e.g.

```
$> kate
```

It just launches normally, without this notification.

My program's core code is essentially this

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    SubclassOfQMainWindow main_window;
    return app .exec ();
}
```

Why does my program launch behind this notification whereas others launch normally?

Comment: did you try `main_window.show()`?

Comment: Yeah. It runs like normal under KDE or other desktop environments. This appears to be GNOME interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, especially without trying your application on my system, but... I have seen similar behavior with dialogs if there is already something that is considered modal that is displayed. In this case, m_searchWindow is a dialog that I want to stay open and on top but it is not modal. Notice that i have to set the WindowStaysOnTopHint or it is behind the modal dialog that is displaying it.

```
m_searchWindow->setWindowFlags(m_searchWindow->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
m_searchWindow->show();
m_searchWindow->raise();
m_searchWindow->activateWindow();
```